# ASP.NET Core How to route in nested Areas

Tags: asp.net-core

[image]

As you can see I split areas in 2 folders. I want those folders to be used to search for Views, Controllers etc...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define this in the Startup.cs class that you are using areas + definition of your structure:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Areas",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

See also areas information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas